# Синонимы "класс" и "круто"

Tags: выбор-слова, синонимы

Я слышал разные способы сказать "класс" или "круто", но не знаю, как правильно использовать их и когда они уместны.

"Пацанский подгон"

"Ништяк"

"Угарчик" (по-моему, это была шутка)

"Классно"

Знаете ли Вы какие-нибудь дополнительные способы выразить это чувство?

Comment: клёво, прикольно, офигеть..

Comment: Зачот (with "о", while correct spelling is "зачёт"). More about internet slang: http://lurkmore.to/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Подгон* на жаргоне означает "подарок, подношение". То есть выражение "пацанский подгон" можно понять как "*достойный подарок*", "подарок, достойный настоящего мужчины" (*пацан* на жаргоне - это что-то вроде macho, bro и т.п.)

*Ништяк* - это довольно многозначное слово. Помимо *круто / cool* вполне может использоваться и в смысле "*ценная вещь*", "особая привилегия" и т.п.

*Угар* (так же как и *прикол*) означает *веселье*, *смех* (fun). В принципе, разница между "весело" и "круто" (fun vs cool) существует, но иногда о ней просто забывают ;-)

*Класс* - слово явно со "школьными" корнями. Лично я его воспринимаю как несколько облегчённую версию "*круто*", но, на самом деле, оба слова весьма распространены и встречаются буквально повсюду. Пытаться найти между ними какие-то различия, это примерно то же самое, что выяснить, чем отличается *cool* от *awesome*.

Кроме указанных слов есть ещё масса других, которые можно использовать для выражения "сильных и светлых" чувств, наподобие *чума*, *отпад*, *зашибись*, *балдёж*, *клёво*, *вот это тема* и пр. и пр. Но вообще, жаргон всегда и везде признак социальной субкультуры. Так что если есть желание ограничиться наиболее обычными формами, приемлемыми для большинства граждан, то это *класс / классно* и *круто*.

Comment: А можно немного подробнее о слове "подгон", ни разу в жизни оно мне не встречалось

Comment: @Olga Подгон -> подогнать/пригнать -> привезти/принести -> подарить. Словцо с уголовно-гопническим душком: [подгон](http://argo.academic.ru/3977/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BD); [босяцкий подгон](http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/187281-chto-oznachaet-vyrazhenie-bosjackij-podgon.html)